# Iptables and bind9 to forward to google's dns

Tags: networking, server, dns, firewall, iptables

Hello i have a very hard time on getting along with **iptables** and **bind9** as my internal network dns server.
It's configured to forward my queries to google's dns (8.8.8.8).

The main problem is i can't configure iptables to allow to speak with my dns.
My main rule is to drop all INPUT and OUTPUT connections and allow only those i require for some services and bind9.

Here is my iptables now

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1155
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:1155 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have tried to use what [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213532/writing-a-simple-firewall-with-iptables) user says but with no luck.

Also i have tried many combinations allowing port 53 for udp and tcp like this

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Also here is what i get from 
**sudo netstat -anp | grep -e tcp -e udp**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1155            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      969/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1179/apache2    
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.22:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1087/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1087/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1087/named      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.22:1155       192.168.0.20:50016      ESTABLISHED 1263/sshd: giorgos 
tcp6       0      0 :::1155                 :::*                    LISTEN      969/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1087/named      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1087/named      
udp        0      0 192.168.0.22:53         0.0.0.0:*                           1087/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1087/named      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           943/dhclient3   
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                1087/named
```

Comment: You redirect all dns req to google dns?

Comment: yeap to 8.8.8.8

Comment: You server have only one ethernet card?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, iptables rule for this can be something like this

this will accept dns req

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

This will create chain to catch dns req

```
sudo iptables -t nat -N CATCH_DNS
sudo iptables -t nat -A CATCH_DNS -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
sudo iptables -t nat -A CATCH_DNS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```

Then you can apply rule on INPUT

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j CATCH_DNS
```

I think this will work :)